# How to use a buffer while writing to a file with c++ boost streams?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to write some strings on a txt file using "Boost C++" libraries but i cannot find online a complete guide about how to do that.
The only thing i have been able to do is this:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;
using namespace std;

io::stream_buffer<io::file_sink> buf("test.txt");
ostream out(&buf);
out<<"Hello world!"<<flush;
```

that simply writes a simple string on the file.

How can i set the buffer size? Is there a way to implement an auto flushing cycle?

Comment: You need to sift through a bunch of baseclasses as well. I'd recommend a look into "C++ IOStreams and Locales" if you want an in-depth introduction to C++ iostreams, although the material is really old. Also, that part of the standardlibrary is kind-of ugly from a design point of view, it will help you understand the base of the Boost code though. If you can't find it in a library, start with cppreference.com, checking out the docs for all the streambuffer-related classes.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. You want to write some strings to a text file. Your code writes a string to a text file. So don't you just need to add more lines like `out<<"Hello world!"<<flush;`? Why worry about buffer size and auto-flushing at this point?

Comment: I don't want to launch a write every string i create. I just want to push a large amount of strings in the buffer and then write it on the file using a flush every time the buffer is ready. I can do it in java but i cannot find no guide about it in boost.